# RSpec: "schema does not exist" when calling a method in one model from a method in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

Trying to follow the law of demeter, I'm in the process of refactoring code. The goal is for every model to have methods that serve as APIs for other models to extract data.

Organization has an instance method #suppliers_for_purchaser, which returns all suppliers for one purchaser. This method has been successfully tested in organization_spec.rb.

Price has a class method .latest_prices_for_purchaser. This class method takes one argument (an instance of Organization) and uses this argument to call Organization#suppliers_for_purchaser. This causes an error **schema does not exist** in RSpec:

```
Failures:

1) Price.latest_prices_for_purchaser returns latest prices for purchaser
 Failure/Error: Price.latest_prices_for_purchaser(purchaser).should have(2).prices
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::Error: ERROR:  schema "organization" does not exist
   : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "organizations" INNER JOIN "partnerships" ON "organizations"."id" = "partnerships"."partner_id" WHERE "partnerships"."organization_id" = 1 AND (organization.organization_role.name = 'supplier')
 # ./spec/models/price_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Models (simplified)

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  # self referencing n:n table
  has_many :partners, :through => :partnerships
  # some more associations, all tested

  # successfully tested in an RSpec unit test for this model
  def suppliers_for_purchaser    
    partners.where('organization.organization_role.name = ?', "supplier")
  end
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.latest_prices_for_purchaser(purchaser)
    suppliers = purchaser.suppliers_for_purchaser
    # some more code that doesn't get executed because it crashes on the line above
  end
end
```

price_spec.rb (simlified)

```
describe Price do
  describe ".latest_prices_for_purchaser" do

    # passes
    it "responds" do
      Price.should respond_to(:latest_prices_for_purchaser)
    end

    it "returns latest prices for purchaser" do
      purchaser = create(:organization_purchaser)
      supplier = create(:organization_supplier)
  partnership = create(:partnership, organization: purchaser, partner: supplier) 
      2.times do
        price = create(:price, created_at: 10.hours.ago, supplier: supplier, purchaser: purchaser)
      end
      Price.latest_prices_for_purchaser(purchaser).should have(2).prices                  
    end

  end
end
```

**Update**

[cheeseweasel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946270/cheeseweasel) found the solution. Unit testing Price.latest_prices_for_purchaser only worked when changing Organization#suppliers_for_purchaser to:

```
partners.joins(:organization_role).where('organization_roles.name = ?', "supplier")
```

Comment: I don't quite see how that would work, but maybe I'm missing something? Could you show us the working test? Also, can't you get rid of this bit: `Organization.find(self).`?

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of `Organization.find(self)`. I also included the working test at the bottom. I'm new to unit testing, generally speaking, is it possible to test one class method that calls an instance method of another model?

Comment: No worries, well your Organization test doesn't test suppliers_for_purchaser which was what I thought you meant. I'm not sure of your exact structure, but does something like this get you anywhere: `partners.joins(:organization_roles).where('organization_roles.name = ?', "supplier")` ?

Comment: Thanks, I think this was a step in the right direction. Error now is `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'organization_roles' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`. I included the factories.rb file so you can see that associations are set. Do they get lost when one method calls the method from the other model?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `joins(:organization_role)`, though it depends on the association name in the model. Does that help?

Comment: Awesome, you solved it. Thanks heaps. Do you happen to know why the join is only necessary when testing through another model (ie Price and not Organization)?

Comment: No worries, I've just put this in an answer. :) You need to always explicitely define joins when you query the database - when you set a where clause like `"organization_roles.name = ?"` this is sql, it's not using rails associations, the first part the table name, and the second the column. You need to join any tables that you want to use in the where clause. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the suppliers_for_purchaser method - when constructing queries, you need to explicitely define any joins to related tables, so the following:

```
partners.where('organization.organization_role.name = ?', "supplier")
```

needs to have the organization_role join defined:

```
partners.joins(:organization_role).where('organization_roles.name = ?', "supplier")
```